# Is there an intransitive verb that means "withdraw money"?

Tags: word-request

Is there an intransitive verb that means "withdraw money"? I am looking for either an intransitive verb that means "withdraw money" or a transitive verb that means "withdraw money" that doesn't have the word "money" or any equivalent thereof as an object.

For example:

> Your company ___ your credit card, because of the cost you've incurred
>   during your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used **credit card** in your example, so the following could apply:

> Your company **charged** your credit card, because of the cost you've incurred during your work.
>
> Your company **debited** your credit card, ...

If you mean a **bank account in general**, you could try the following:

> Alice **withdrew money from** her family's account.
>
> Alice **debited** her family's account.
>
> Alice **dipped into** her family's account.
>
> Alice **used** her family's account.

The *Cambridge Dictionary* covers ["**withdrawing money**"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/topics/finance/withdrawing-money/) if you need more background.